# "ValueError: unconverted data remains: " when converting pandas column to the following datetime format '%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

This is my code.

`df_log['DateTime']= pd.to_datetime('2010 '+ df_log['DateTime'], format='%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')`

This is how the DataFrame looks like:

```
DateTime    LogHost ApplicationProcess  LogMessage  AccessType
0   Jun 14 15:16:01 combo   sshd(pam_unix)[19939]   authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 ...   Unauthorized
1   Jun 14 15:16:02 combo   sshd(pam_unix)[19937]   check pass; user unknown    NaN
2   Jun 14 15:16:02 combo   sshd(pam_unix)[19937]   authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 ...   Unauthorized
3   Jun 15 02:04:59 combo   sshd(pam_unix)[20882]   authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 ...   Unauthorized
4   Jun 15 02:04:59 combo   sshd(pam_unix)[20884]   authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 ...   Unauthorized
```

My ideal output is to convert DateTime column from object to datetime64[ns]

However, i keep getting the error as shown

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    447             try:
--> 448                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    449                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)

pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-9b47aa7f900a> in <module>
      7 #pd.Timestamp.min
      8 #pd.Timestamp.max
----> 9 df_log['DateTime']= pd.to_datetime('2010 '+ df_log['DateTime'], format='%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')
     10 
     11 df_log.info()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    206                 else:
    207                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 208             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    209 
    210         return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    772                 result = result.tz_localize(tz)
    773     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
--> 774         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    775         if not cache_array.empty:
    776             result = arg.map(cache_array)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    154         unique_dates = unique(arg)
    155         if len(unique_dates) < len(arg):
--> 156             cache_dates = convert_listlike(unique_dates, True, format)
    157             cache_array = Series(cache_dates, index=unique_dates)
    158     return cache_array

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    449                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
    450             except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 451                 raise e
    452 
    453     if result is None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    414                 try:
    415                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
--> 416                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors
    417                     )
    418                     if "%Z" in format or "%z" in format:

pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Any advise on how to solve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If I add `'Jun 15 02:04:59 '` to the `Datetime` column, I get the same error.  So I'm guessing your `DateTime` column has spaces.
- To resolve the issue:

  - Use `.str.strip()` to remove the whitespace
  - Remove the `format` parameter

```py
import pandas as pd

# data
data = {'DateTime': ['Jun 14 15:16:01', 'Jun 14 15:16:02', 'Jun 14 15:16:02', 'Jun 15 02:04:59', 'Jun 15 02:04:59 ']}

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

         DateTime
  Jun 14 15:16:01
  Jun 14 15:16:02
  Jun 14 15:16:02
  Jun 15 02:04:59
 Jun 15 02:04:59 

print(type(df.DateTime[0]))

>>> <class 'str'>

# original method
df['original method'] = pd.to_datetime('2010 '+ df['DateTime'].str.strip(), format='%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')

# alternate method
df['alternate method'] = pd.to_datetime('2010 '+ df['DateTime'])

print(df)

           DateTime     original method    alternate method
    Jun 14 15:16:01 2010-06-14 15:16:01 2010-06-14 15:16:01
    Jun 14 15:16:02 2010-06-14 15:16:02 2010-06-14 15:16:02
    Jun 14 15:16:02 2010-06-14 15:16:02 2010-06-14 15:16:02
    Jun 15 02:04:59 2010-06-15 02:04:59 2010-06-15 02:04:59
 Jun  15  02:04:59  2010-06-15 02:04:59 2010-06-15 02:04:59
```